# Grub cannot find Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I am dual booting windows 10 and ubuntu 17.04 on separate hard drives.  I had recently been running ubuntu 16.04, but I think an update screwed with X11, so I had to wipe it and start fresh.  Grub now cannot find Windows 10.  os-prober didn't work.  I ran boot-repair to get [this log](https://paste2.org/IHge2LAM). How can I fix this?  All other solutions I have come across either suggest UEFI is not right, which the logs seem to suggest is not the case, or to run update-grub, which didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Windows is installed in UEFI-mode. Ubuntu has been installed in UEFI-mode too, but when you reinstalled Ubuntu you reinstalled Ubuntu in legacy-mode. You can still see the Ubuntu files in the ESP from your first install, but a look at `fstab` shows clearly that the current install is in legacy-mode (EFI-partition is not mounted!), also we can see that Grub is installed in the MBR of `sdb`.

You may use Boot-Repairs `recommended repair` to solve this, the important thing is, that you have to boot your installer in UEFI-mode to do that (look at line 791 in your log). When booting from USB you should have two options, on my machine it is something like `USB2.0` or `UEFI:USB2.0`, the first option would boot in legacy mode, the latter in UEFI-mode.

Your mistake happened when you booted the installer to reinstall Ubuntu, remember: how you boot is how you install! If you boot the installer in legacy-mode, Ubuntu will be installed in legacy-mode, if you boot the installer in UEFI-mode, Ubuntu will be installed in UEFI-mode.

Even for the use of Boot-Repair we have to choose the correct boot-mode, as UEFI-features are not supported when we boot in legacy-mode. Your log shows, that you started in legacy-mode to run Boot-Repair, that is ok to create the log, but to reinstall Grub in UEFI-mode you have to run Boot-Repair in UEFI-mode!